# Raised Fragment Look

Tags: android, android-fragments

Not really sure how to explain this but how can I make 2 fragments look like one is higher than the other as seen in this picture

[image]

as you can see the right edge of the `listview` looks like it is lower than the fragment to the right. How can this be accomplished? I am trying to make my layout not look so one dimensional/flat.

Comment: I believe the background of the `Fragment` on the left just fades to a darker color to appear as a drop shadow of the center `Fragment`. Additionally, I think the arrow is done as an image overlaying the background, so it appears to line up with the center's background.

Comment: Im not really interested in the arrow just the "fading edge"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is actually done with a simple resource. The right side of the listview on the left has a simple drop shadow graphic attached to it. The graphic is repeated for each row that's not selected (as you can see it's replaced with arrow on the row that is) You can just pick a color and use the gradient tool in photoshop (or gimp or what ever). Fade that in over a few pixels and use that as your edge.

Comment: looking through the source of the contacts apk that edge is an image with a gradient

Answer (score 10):

While Frank's answer is good, you can actually do this without graphics, using [Android's internal `gradient` XML resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="180"
        android:centerX="0.1"
        android:startColor="#555"
        android:centerColor="#aaa"
        android:endColor="#aaa"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

- `android:angle` says to do it horizontally, right-to-left
- `android:centerX` says to move the "center" of the gradient so it's 10% from the start of the gradient.
- `android:startColor` is the color to display at the right.
- `android:centerColor` is the color to display in the center.
- `android:endColor` is the color to display at the end. This is the same as `centerColor` because we want to keep it a solid color except for the shadow.
- `android:type` makes it linear, obviously.

You'll want to play around a bit with the colors, I just estimated.

Comment: this helped me out allot! Way easier than using a graphic since you can manipulate this in code!